# Unable to import spring configuration class from project A into project B

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit

I have below classes in **project A** which is a spring project

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig{
   @Bean
   JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(){
       return  new JmsTemplate();
   }

   @Bean
   Test test(){
       return new Test();
   }
}

class Test{
   @Autowired
   JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

   @PostConstuct
   public void init(){
      System.out.println("Test Constructed")
   }

   public void sendOrder(){
      System.out.println("Sending Order");
   }
}
```

And I have below in **Project B**

```
@SpringBootApplication
class MySpringBootApp{

    public static void main(String[] args){
     final SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MainConfig.class);
     app.run(args);
    }
}

@Configuration
@Import(MyConfig.class)
class MainConfig implements CommandLineRunner{

   @Autowired 
   Test test;

   @Override
   public void run(String... strings) throws Exception{
      System.out.println("Placing order");
      test.sendOrder()
   } 
}
```

I have included project A in the pom of project B as dependency

Neither SYS OUT from post construct or sendOrder from Test class is printed. SYS OUT in run method from MainConfig is printed .. I am not sure if MyConfig class from project A is included in project B,  There are no compilation nor run-time errors. Any leads appreciated

Comment: try annotating  MyConfig class with @Configuration

Comment: In your main class why you have mentioned MainConfig.class. I think it should be Myspringbootapp.class which is your mainboot class. Also check your class Test of package A, cant see it’s component class or what?

Comment: Added @Configuration to MyConfig, but didnt work.

Comment: @coder i have given my comment can you please implement and test it again.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, i added MySpingBootApp but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the main class.
You forgot to include the spring boot application itself (`MySpringBootApp.class` in this case) into the configuration list.

It should be:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class MySpringBootApp{

 public static void main(String[] args){
  final SpringApplication app = new 
           SpringApplication(MySpringBootApp.class,MainConfig.class);
  app.run(args);
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi i added MySpringBootApp class into the configuration list, but still no luck. Not sure what is missing?